# Separate a string into different Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, nsarray

I have a string coming from server , i want to show some part of string in a view and rest part of string in other view .

Thanks for help.

i want to get the last word of last line of first view. i have searched ,but nothing seems to help me. If any one can suggest me something i would be glad to him/her.

```
 NSString *fromIndex = [_categoryWiseNews.article substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, lastWordOfFirstView)];
```

i have tried with **substringWithRange** but with this you have to know the lastWordOfFirstView index number for breaking the string into two parts, for which i have no idea.

Comment: Want help in IOS , objc c if possible..

Comment: Please edit your question to add these as tags, and people will have an easier time finding your question and answering it!

Comment: And please add some code you've tried, we won't write it for you!

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Would it be possible to add some more details. What does the string from the server look like? What do you mean by "the last word of the last line of the first view"? Have you tried anything so far? What results did you get?

Comment: @Fogmeister - I've two UITextView on which i have to show text, this text is a single string . Firstly , the half string is shown on first textView and then the remaining half string i have to show on next TextView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know what it is that you're asking `lastWordOfFirstView` might make sense to you because it is relevant to the thing you are working on. But to us it means nothing.

You can separate a string into words in an array doing this...

```
NSString *string = @"Hello world, this is a string";

NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

// array is now... [@"Hello", @"world,", @"this", @"is", @"a", @"string"];
```

Then you can get the last word from it...

```
NSString *lastWord = [array lastObject];
```

Comment: Is there any possible way to find the last line of the Textview??

Comment: @adi Not easily. If you take a look at the "Core Text" framework you may be able to use that to find where the text is breaking onto the last line.

Comment: i didn't understand the "Core Text" . What you mean to say with this??

Comment: Google it. It's a framework. Actually, I think it's called "TextKit".

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the last word from a sentence:

```
NSString *lastWord = [[fullSentenceString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] lastObject];
```

Comment: Is there any possible way to find the last line of the Textview??